# Can we use binary search to find most frequently occuring integer in sorted array?

Tags: arrays, performance, algorithm, sorting, frequency

**Problem**:

Given a sorted array of integers find the most frequently occurring integer. If there are multiple integers that satisfy this condition, return any one of them.

**My basic solution:**

Scan through the array and keep track of how many times you've seen each integer. Since it's sorted, you know that once you see a different integer, you've gotten the frequency of the previous integer. Keep track of which integer had the highest frequency.

This is O(N) time, O(1) space solution.

I am wondering if there's a more efficient algorithm that uses some form of binary search. It will still be O(N) time, but it should be faster for the average case.

Comment: It doesn't look that way, imagine the case where each element is present only once, so any element is a valid answer. But there's no way to tell this is the case until you checked every single element.

Comment: In order to talk about average case, you need to define some probability distribution for the possible inputs. For algorithms like quicksort there is a natural probability distribution that can be used, but I don't see what you'd use here.

Comment: I posted an algorithm that uses O((n/k) log k) probes, where k is the frequency of the most frequently occurring integer. This is asymptotically optimal in n and k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asymptotically (big-oh wise), you cannot use binary search to improve the worst case, for the reasons the answers above mine have presented. However, here are some ideas that may or may not help you in practice.

For each integer, binary search for its last occurrence. Once you find it, you know how many times it appears in the array, and can update your counts accordingly. Then, continue your search from the position you found.

This is advantageous if you have only a few elements that repeat a lot of times, for example:

```
1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

Because you will only do 3 binary searches. If, however, you have many distinct elements:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Then you will do `O(n)` binary searches, resulting in `O(n log n)` complexity, so worse.

This gives you a better best case and a worse worst case than your initial algorithm.

Can we do better? We could improve the worst case by finding the last occurrence of the number at position `i` like this: look at `2i`, then at `4i` etc. as long as the value at those positions are the same. If they are not, look at `(i + 2i) / 2` etc.

For example, consider the array:

```
i
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ...
1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

We look at `2i = 2`, it has the same value. We look at `4i = 4`, same value. We look at `8i = 8`, different value. We backtrack to `(4 + 8) / 2 = 6`. Different value. Backtrack to `(4 + 6) / 2 = 5`. Same value. Try `(5 + 6) / 2 = 5`, same value. We search no more, because our window has width 1, so we're done. Continue the search from position `6`.

This should improve the best case, while keeping the worst case as fast as possible.

Asymptotically, nothing is improved. To see if it actually works better on average in practice, you'll have to test it.

Comment: I don't think that there's much value in improving the best case, unless you know that it's more likely that the input given is actually the best case. But we know no such thing.

Comment: I think this is the best answer apart from "no". :)

Comment: @interjay - true, but it might also behave better on average. Also, if it's not significantly worse in the worst case, then you might as well improve at least the best case.

Comment: @biziclop I think the best answer is "no" and adding more only confuses the matter.

Comment: @interjay I think there is merit to trying to find restrictions on the problem space that allow for a better algorithm. Not necessarily in practice, I agree, but in mapping out the internal structure of the problem. But also in practice sometimes, just look at the sheer number of systems that use sparse matrices, doing things that wouldn't be possible if we just stuck to universal matrix operations.

Comment: @biziclop And yet, if someone asks what the fastest algorithm is for matrix multiplication, it wouldn't help to give them a sparse matrix multiplication algorithm, even if it would be faster for the sparse matrix case.

Answer (score 1):

Binary search, which eliminates half of the remaining candidates, probably wouldn't work. There are some techniques you could use to avoid reading every element in the array. Unless your array is extremely long or you're solving a problem for curiosity, the naive (linear scan) solution is probably good enough.

Here's why I think binary search wouldn't work: start with an array: given the value of the middle item, you do not have enough information to eliminate the lower or upper half from the search.

However, we can scan the array in multiple passes, each time checking twice as many elements. When we find two elements that are the same, make one final pass. If no other elements were repeated, you've found the longest element run (without even knowing how many of that element is in the sorted list).
 Otherwise, investigate the two (or more) longer sequences to determine which is longest.

Consider a sorted list.

```
Index 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f
List  1 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 5 5 6 6 6 7
Pass1 1 . . . . . . 3 . . . . . . . 7
Pass2 1 . . 3 . . . 3 . . . 5 . . . 7
Pass3 1 2 . 3 . x . 3 . 4 . 5 . 6 . 7
```

After pass 3, we know that the run of 3's must be at least 5, while the longest run of any other number is at most 3. Therefore, 3 is the most frequently occurring number in the list.

Using the right data structures and algorithms (use binary-tree-style indexing), you can avoid reading values more than once. You can also avoid reading the 3 (marked as an x in pass 3) since you already know its value.

This solution has running time `O(n/k)` which degrades to `O(n)` for `k=1` for a list with n elements and a longest run of k elements. For small k, the naive solution will perform better due to simpler logic, data structures, and higher RAM cache hits.

If you need to determine the frequency of the most common number, it would take `O((n/k) log k)` as indicated by David to find the first and last position of the longest run of numbers using binary search on up to `n/k` groups of size `k`.

Comment: [As I pointed out half an hour before your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25711973/2144669), the binary searches to find the extent of Omega(n/k) groups take Theta((n/k) log k) time.

Answer (score 0):

The worst case cannot be better than O(n) time. Consider the case where each element exists once, except for one element which exists twice. In order to find that element, you'd need to look at every element in the array until you find it. This is because knowing the value of any array element does not give you any information regarding the location of the duplicate element, until it's actually found. This is in contrast to binary search, where the value of an array element allows you to rule out many other elements.

Comment: I think the case you describe (each element exists once, except for one which exists twice) is one exception where it can actually done using binary search...

Comment: @JoSo Then provide an algorithm that does so. But it's possible to prove that any algorithm would require at least n array lookups in the worst case.

Comment: (If we knew beforehand that each element exists once except for one which exists twice) you can easily detect *whether* the duplicate falls in a given range. So just divide it recursively. Extra care must be taken for the case when the duplicate sequence is split in two.

Comment: @JoSo You can't detect whether the duplicate falls in a given range as you claim, without searching the whole range.

Comment: "at least n array lookups" Not quite; returning the middle element out of three is correct and only one lookup. In general, we can avoid examining one end of the array or the other.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat You're right, one or two lookups can be avoided.

Comment: @interjay: By "range", I meant a slice of the input array. You can detect whether the duplicate is in the slice simply by comparing the length of the slice to the difference of the leftmost and the rightmost element in the slice...

Comment: @JoSo No you can't. What you're saying only works if the array contains consecutive numbers.

Comment: @interjay: "each element exists once"... Let's leave it at that, it doesn't lead anywhere

Answer (score 0):

No, in the worst case we have to scan at least n - 2 elements, but see
below for an algorithm that exploits inputs with many duplicates.

Consider an adversary that, for the first n - 3 distinct probes into the
n-element array, returns m for the value at index m. Now the algorithm
knows that the array looks like

```
1 2 3 ... i-1 ??? i+1 ... j-1 ??? j+1 ... k-1 ??? k+1 ... n-2 n-1 n.
```

Depending on what the `???`s are, the sole correct answer could be `j-1`
or `j+1`, so the algorithm isn’t done yet.

This example involved an array where there were very few duplicates. In
fact, we can design an algorithm that, if the most frequent element
occurs k times out of n, uses O((n/k) log k) probes into the array. For
j from ceil(log2(n)) - 1 down to 0, examine the subarray consisting of
every (2**j)th element. Stop if we find a duplicate. The cost so far
is O(n/k). Now, for each element in the subarray, use binary search to
find its extent (O(n/k) searches in subarrays of size O(k), for a total
of O((n/k) log k)).

It can be shown that all algorithms have a worst case of Omega((n/k) log
k), making this one optimal in the worst case up to constant factors.